# Animate to CSS value using JQuery's animate()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to animate an element's style to the value defined using CSS. I don't want to animate to the default value, so `animate({'width':'auto'})` won't work.

For example:

```
<style>
#element{width:100px;}
</style>

<div id=element></div>

<script>
$('#element').width(200);
$('#element').animate({width:'auto'});
</script>
```

Is there a way to animate the element back to its original width without using a Javascript variable?

Comment: So you want to animate from `100px` (original) to `200px` and then back to `100px`?

Comment: What's the issue against using a JS variable?

Comment: @stackErr: That's right.

Comment: @j08691: I'm changing the width from different scopes, so it would get messy if I using variables. I'd use variables as a last resort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try one of the following approaches:

1. If `width` and `animate` are in the same scope, you can do something like this (store initial width before setting a new one in local var and use it in `animate`):

   ```
   var initialWidth = $('#element').width(); // or $('#element').css('width')
   $('#element').width(200);
   $('#element').animate({width:initialWidth});
   ```
2. If you call `animate` some time later and not able to use local var because it would be out of scope, you can store your initial width in `data` attribute

   ```
   var initialWidth = $('#element').width(); // or $('#element').css('width')
   $('#element').data('initial-width', initialWidth);
   $('#element').width(200);
   ```

   then retrieve it when you call `animate`:

   ```
   var initialWidth = $('#element').data('initial-width');
   $('#element').animate({width: initialWidth});
   ```

See working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Hc5b9/) for approach #2 with **no JS variables** used

Comment: The OP specifically requested "without using a Javascript variable"

Comment: Take a look at my second approach, no variable is used

Comment: While I understand what you try to say, I think that's overcomplicating. If I were to use such approach, I would just change the html and do something like <div id='#element' init-width='200px'></div> and extract it with jQuery like you did.

Comment: you would do this, somebody else would do differently while this was in the question "I want to animate an element's style to the value defined using CSS. I don't want to animate to the default value"

Comment: and using `data` attribute is in no way overcomplicating things, that's what it is for to "Store arbitrary data associated with the matched elements"... using custom properties like `init-width` in your example is a very bad practice and will be considered a warning or an error by the html validator

Comment: Yep, init-width was a bad example, sorry for that. For the other things, I think it is an opinion based discussion so I'll stop it there.

Answer (score 0):

You can workaround your "no js variable" requirement by using an **auxiliar html markup**.

```
<style>
$aux_element {width:100px; display: none;}
#element, width:100px;}
</style>

<div id='aux_element'></div>
<div id='element'></div>

<script>
$('#element').width(200);
$('#element').animate({width: $('#aux_element').css('width');});
</script>
```

[Here a working js fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/HectorWasHere/uT3GC/)